# Why does this vowel counting fail?

Tags: javascript

```
function VowelCount(str) {
  var counter=0;
  for(i=0; i<str.length; i++)
  {
    if (/[AEIOUaeiou]/g.test(str[i]))
    {
      counter += 1;
    }
  }
  return counter; 
}

VowelCount("aaaeeebziiiooouu");
```

This returns "14" on repl.it, but returns only "7" on coderbyte.

What have I missed?

Comment: Why not just use `return str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;`?

Comment: You've missed the fact that coderbyte may be buggy.

Comment: If you are only testing against one character, you don't need the `g`.

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: Keep the g. Drop the loop.

Comment: coderbyte hates the extra g (thanks Mr. Hazmat) Removing the g makes everything work.

Comment: @Jeffman .test returns a boolean, so dropping the loop would not tell him how many vowels exist in the string, just if one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user1544566 discovered the answer to this question and posted it in the comments, but he didn't write an answer for it. He said:

```
coderbyte hates the extra g (thanks Mr. Hazmat) Removing the g makes everything work.
```

Apparently, Coderbyte runs the code you submitted incorrectly. It appears you've found a bug. I'd consider reporting it to them.

Answer (score 2):

While others are right and you should use `match` instead. You asked why it wasn't working and it's because you set the `g` flag on your regex, so it will keep track of the `lastIndex` of the previous match and start looking from that index on for subsequent matches.

E.g.

```
var rx = /a/g;

rx.test('aa'); //true

console.log(rx.lastIndex); //1

rx.test('a'); //false
```

Comment: Yes, but this is the standard behavior - that doesn't explain why he's getting different results. I guess the engine running on coderbyte (node?) caches regex literals somehow, while others instantiate a new regex object on each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `match` and count its `length`:

```
function vowelCount(str) {
  return (str.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length;
}
```

> What have I missed?

**Edit:** Your code works fine here http://jsbin.com/osesoh/1/edit

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: Mine was a beginner's solution. I'll use your match version from now on though! Thanks.

Comment: Your solution will break if there are no matches. One possible fix is `return (str.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length;`